# Need assitance with pulling JSON item

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am working with a JSON DB and displaying ingredients on the page. I have a separate HTML page for each recipe. I am creating an unordered list on the page and manually typing in the recipe ingredients for the recipe on the page.

I am trying to pull in the recipe name from the DB but I cant get it to show. I want to pull in the correct item if it matches the item UPC in the DB. Please see below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 'use strict';

  $.ajax({
     dataType: "jsonp",
     url: '',
     success: function(data){

         $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            $('#recipeIngredients').html(
            "<ul>" + 
                "<li>" + '1/2 tsp sugar' + "</li>" +
                "<li>" + '1/2 tsp salt' + "</li>" +
                "<li>" + '3 tbsp ' + (item.itemFullUPC == "070796150062" ? item.itemName : "" ) + "</li>" +
                "<li>" + '1 pkg active dry yeast' + "</li>" +
                "<li>" + '3/4 cup warm water' + "</li>" +
                "<li>" + '2 tbsp ' + (item.itemFullUPC == "070796150012" ? item.itemName : "" ) + "</li>" +
                "<li>" + '2 cups shredded mozzarella cheese' + "</li>" +
            "</ul>"
            ); 
         }); 

    } }) });
```

Comment: You don't seem so be sending any filtering information to the DB.

Comment: im trying to do it with this item "<li>" + '2 tbsp ' + (item.itemFullUPC == "070796150012" ? item.itemName : "" ) + "</li>" +

Comment: basically if itemFullUPC = "value in database", show item name that corresponds to that value. do i have something wrong with my if statement?

Comment: What is the value of item? Do you have a return from DB?

Comment: What you seem to be doing is getting all the data and then iterating over all of them. The one's which matching UPC have their item name printed else it uses empty string. Is this correct? Or you want to get the filtered data from DB itself?

Comment: im not sure im still learning this stuff. but all i want to do if do an if statement in my code (so if the item UPC is selected for the item in the DB, show that items name)

Comment: You may also want to open browser's debugger net tab and capture the response for above request and paste  it here.

Comment: @AnuragSinha i need the filtered data. if itemFullUPC == "070796150012", i need to show the itemName for that one in the list in the appropriate list item above

Comment: `if (item.itemFullUPC == "070796150012") { $("recipeIngredients").html(...); }`

Comment: @Barmar im gonna have multiple items in the list that will need different item names from the DB. this only works for one item for everything correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the HTML every time through the loop, so the final result will just be from the last item in the array.

Instead, you should use an `if` statement, and only display the items that matches the UPC code you want.

Then you should use `.append()` rather than `.html()` so you add the `<ul>` to the list, instead of overwriting it.

```
     $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        if (item.itemFullUPC == "070796150012") {
            $('#recipeIngredients').append(
                "<ul>" + 
                    "<li>" + '1/2 tsp sugar' + "</li>" +
                    "<li>" + '1/2 tsp salt' + "</li>" +
                    "<li>" + '1/2 tsp salt' + "</li>" +
                    "<li>" + '1 pkg active dry yeast' + "</li>" +
                    "<li>" + '3/4 cup warm water' + "</li>" +
                    "<li>" + '2 tbsp ' + item.itemName + "</li>" +
                    "<li>" + '2 cups shredded mozzarella cheese' + "</li>" +
                "</ul>"
            );
        }
     });
```

Comment: this works but in the list im going to have multiple items. please see my original post above. i edited it to show you what I mean. but also thank you

Comment: I changed it to use `.append()` instead of `.html()` so it will have all of them.

Comment: what if i have multiple items im trying to show in the list?

Comment: You mean more than one UPC code? You can put them all in an array, and use `if (UPCCodes.indexOf(item.itemFullUPC) > -1)`

Comment: Yes that's what I mean

Comment: But will I be able to choose an item like that?

Comment: You can have multiple form inputs, and collect all of them into an array, then use that code.